# Is the converse of Vertically opposite angles true?

Tags: geometry, triangles, rectangles

When two straight lines intersect the vertically opposite angles are equal.

But, can we say that, if the vertically opposite angles of two lines are equal then the lines are straight?

[image]

The angles marked equal in orange, come after comparing the two congruent triangles, in the attached image.

Comment: That would depend on what you mean by "line", and how you propose to define the angle between two things that aren't lines.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "vertically opposite angles".

Comment: There's only one straight line joining $A$ and $C$, and it goes through the center of the square. Ditto, $B$ and $D$. If $E$ is not the center of the square, it follows that neither $AEC$ nor $BED$ is a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your attached image shows, having a pair of opposite angles that are equal is not enough to deduce that you have two straight lines - angles $\angle AED$ and $\angle BEC$ are shown to be equal, but even visually you can see that AC and BD are not straight lines.

However, if *both* pairs of opposite angles are equal - so in the diagram, if we also had $\angle AEB = \angle CED$ - then since the angles around a point sum to $360^\circ$ we can note that $\angle AED + \angle AEB + \angle BEC + \angle CED = 2(\angle AED + \angle AEB) = 360^\circ$ and so $\angle AED + \angle AEB = 180^\circ$ which *is* sufficient to prove that BD is a straight line, and similarly for AC.